# Why is Netbeans 9 (nightly) blurry on Windows 10 when Netbeans 8 isn't?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-9

I've been running NetBeans 8.2 on JDK 8 and it's perfectly fine.  However, I now am moving to JDK 9.  NetBeans 9.0 is *still* not release ready, so I am running nightly builds.  One thing I've noted already is that the NetBeans nightly builds all have blurry text.  I can bring up 8.2 and 9 beta on the same screen side by side and 8.2 is crisp and 9.0 is blurry.  I'd originally thought it was due to Java 9, but running my existing Java apps in the JRE for 9 are nice and crisp.  Appears to be limited to NetBeans.  Are there any options I can flip in NetBeans 9 beta to have it generate crisp text/emulate 8.2 behaviour instead of generating this blurry text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a workaround:

- Find the NetBeans icon down in the ProgramData/Windows/Start Menu path
- Open properties
- Compatibility tab
- Change "Override high DPI scaling behavior..." to "System" option

Comment: On Windows 10, the "Change high DPI settings" button must be clicked on the Compatibility tab to find the "Override high DPI scaling behavior..." options.